# Updating a dictionary item within an outer dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm a bit confused by the following code.   I would have expected that only the 'D' value in the 'Bob' outer dictionary would have been changed, but instead all the 'D' items have been updated.  Any ideas as to what is going on here?

```
import pprint

def test():
    nameList = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
    itemList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    nameDict = {}    
    zeroItemDict = {}
    
    for i in itemList:
        zeroItemDict[i] = 0
    for n in nameList:
        nameDict[n] = zeroItemDict

    print("Inital Dictionary - All Zeros")
    pp.pprint(nameDict)


    print("\nShould update the 'D' item of 'Bob'")
    nameDict["Bob"]["D"] = 42
    
    pp.pprint(nameDict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

RESULTS:

```
Inital Dictionary - All Zeros

{   'Alice': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0},
    'Bob': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0},
    'Charlie': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0}}

Should update the 'D' item of 'Bob'

{   'Alice': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 42, 'E': 0},
    'Bob': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 42, 'E': 0},
    'Charlie': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 42, 'E': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object*. So when you are doing `nameDict[n] = zeroItemDict` it means a shallow copy of `zeroItemDict` is assigned to every key of `nameList`. Any changes made to `zeroItemDict` will reflect in all of the copies made.

To avoid this use `copy.deepcopy` when you're assigning `zeroItemDict` like this `nameDict[n] = copy.deepcopy(zeroItemDict)`.

**Note:** The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects

[Read more about shallow and deep copy operations.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy)

Comment: Thank you.  That cleared it up (both practically and conceptually).